# Count the number of processes and send a email to multiple people if it exceeds certain limit

Tags: shell-script, email, monitoring, processes

As part of smooth functioning on my application I want to check a count of a particular process and send a email to multiple people if it exceeds certain limit.I have written script for counting process but I dont know for the email part.

Code for processes count

```
#!/bin/sh
NOP=`ps -ef | grep -I nagios.cfg | grep -v grep |wc -l`
if [ $NOP -gt 2 ]
then
(
echo "More parent processes are running on the server"
)
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail command is pretty simple:

```
echo "More parent processes are running on the server" | mail -s "subject" user@example.org user2@example.org
```

And your script can be optimized to one line:

```
[ "$(pgrep -c nagios.cfg)" -gt 2 ] && echo "More parent processes are running on the server" | mail -s "subject" user@example.org user2@example.org
```

Answer (score 1):

how about simple mail command in the end.

it sends email to abc@xyz.com

```
#!/bin/sh
NOP=`ps -ef | grep -I nagios.cfg | grep -v grep |wc -l`
if [ $NOP -gt 2 ]
then
(
echo "More parent processes are running on the server" | mail -s "More parent processes are running on the server"  abc@xyz.com
)
fi
```